# What's a good name for "total wall clock time of all cpus?"

Tags: performance, time

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation
>   and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

My app is reporting CPU time, and people reasonably want to know how much time this is out of, so they can compute % CPU utilized.  My question is, what's the name for the wall clock time times the number of CPUs?

If you add up the total user, system, idle, etc. time for a system, you get the total wall clock time, times the number of CPUs.  What's a good name for that?  According to Wikipedia, [CPU time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time) is:

> CPU time (or CPU usage, process time) is the amount of time for which
>   a central processing unit (CPU) was used for processing instructions
>   of a computer program, as opposed to, for example, waiting for
>   input/output (I/O) operations.

"total time" suggests just wall clock time, and doesn't connote that over a 10 second span, a four-cpu system would have 40 seconds of "total time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Total Wall Clock Time of all CPUs`

Naming things **is** hard, why waste a good 'un once you've found it ?

Comment: That was my suggestion, but an identifier called wall_clock_time_of_all_cpus was deemed too long.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate time: 15 of 40 seconds.